Dynamic order by in clickhouse row_number()
I have (24.1.4.20) view in clickhouse and want change order by columns inside over() of row_number().
create or replace view data.v1 as
select row_number() over(order by COLUMNS({p_order_by:String})) as rn,
       ...

Is it possible to use something like this?
select *
from   data.v1(p_order_by = 'col1,col2,col3...')


According to https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select#dynamic-column-selection
{p_order_by:String} is regexp
so you could try to use col1|col2|col3
